# Is it possible for a pandas dataframe column to have datetime.date type?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I am using cx_oracle to fetch date from databases. I would like to put the fetched data into a pandas dataframe. My problem is that the dates are converted to `numpy.datetime64` objects which I absolutely don't need.

I would like to have them as datetime.date objects. I have seen the `dt.date` method but it still gives back numpy datetypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: It appears that with pandas 0.21.0 or newer, there is no problem holding python `datetime.date`s in a DataFrame. `date-like` columns are not automatically converted to `datetime64[ns]` dtype.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT

print(pd.__version__)
# 0.21.0.dev+25.g50e95e0
dates = [DT.date(2017,1,1)+DT.timedelta(days=2*i) for i in range(3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'foo': np.arange(len(dates))})
print(all([isinstance(item, DT.date) for item in df['dates']]))
# True
df['dates'] = (df['dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1))
print(all([isinstance(item, DT.date) for item in df['dates']]))
# True
```

---

For older versions of Pandas:

There is a way to prevent a Pandas DataFrame from automatically converting
datelike values to `datetime64[ns]` by assigning an additional value such as an
empty string *which is not datelike* to the column. After the DataFrame is
formed, you can remove the non-datelike value:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
dates = [DT.date(2017,1,1)+DT.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['']+dates})
df = df.iloc[1:]
print(all([isinstance(item, DT.date) for item in df['dates']]))
# True
```

Clearly, programming this kind of shenanigan into serious code feels entirely wrong since we're subverting the intent of the developers.
There are also computational speed advantages to using `datetime64[ns]`s over lists or object arrays of `datetime.dates`.
Moreover, if `df[col]` has dtype `datetime64[ns]` then `df[col].dt.date.values` returns an object NumPy array of python `datetime.date`s:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
dates = [DT.datetime(2017,1,1)+DT.timedelta(days=2*i) for i in range(3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates})
print(repr(df['dates'].dt.date.values))
# array([datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), datetime.date(2017, 1, 3),
#        datetime.date(2017, 1, 5)], dtype=object)
```

So you could perhaps enjoy the best of both worlds by keeping the column as `datetime64[ns]` and using `df[col].dt.date.values` to obtain `datetime.date`s when necessary.

On the other hand, the `datetime64[ns]`s and Python `datetime.date`s have different ranges of representable dates.

- `datetime64[ns]`s can represent datetimes from [`1678 AD` to `2262 AD`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html).
- `datetime.date`s can represent dates from `DT.date(0,1,1)` to `DT.date(9999,1,1)`.

If the reason why you want to use `datetime.date`s instead of `datetime64[ns]`s is to overcome the limited range of representable dates, then perhaps [a better alternative is to use a `pd.PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
dates = [DT.date(2017,1,1)+DT.timedelta(days=2*i) for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.PeriodIndex(dates, freq='D')})
print(df)
#        dates
# 0 2017-01-01
# 1 2017-01-03
# 2 2017-01-05
# 3 2017-01-07
# 4 2017-01-09
# 5 2017-01-11
# 6 2017-01-13
# 7 2017-01-15
# 8 2017-01-17
# 9 2017-01-19
```